# How To Marshal Return Values Of WinApi Functions?

Tags: c#, winapi, marshalling

**Simple:** How can I **explicitly marshal** the result of a WinAPi function ?

---

I know how to marshal parameters of WinApi functions in C# but how can I also marshal the return values ? Or do I actually have to marshal them ? I understand WinAPi returns only `BOOL` or all types of `INT` (handles are int as well in unmanaged code).

```
// common signature
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern int GetFileAttributes([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string filename);

// my prefered signature because easy to handle the result
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern FileAttributes GetFileAttributes([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string filename);
```

Since `FileAttributes` is enum and each value can easily be cast to `int` I'm sure I'm safe with this notation. But can I marshal the result in this one signature like I do with the parameters ? I actually only know `Marshal` class and `MarshalAs` attribute.

Comment: Why in the world are you explicitly calling the ANSI version of the function? The year 1998 called, they want their code back.

Comment: @CodyGray Because Google and the rest of the internet is full of Ansi versions of this function. I have already worked out all 3 versions but this is just an example.

Comment: I don't really believe that, but even if it is true, that doesn't make it right. At a minimum, you want `CharSet.Auto`, but anymore, there's really no reason not to use `CharSet.Unicode` unless you're targeting .NET 2.0 and Windows 98.

Comment: This doesn't belong here but I worked with `Ansi` until today when I **finally** found out how to make `Auto` work. Because it didn't. pinvoke didn't supply my knowledge with enough information about that. Now I have for all my WinApi file-functions all 3 signatures implemented so I can switch between them. If you say Unicode is the way to go. I will remember that and take it into account next time. Ok ?

Comment: You have to use the appropriate string type, too, or it won't work. That would be `UnmanagedType.LPWStr` for Unicode, and `UnmanagedType.LPTStr` for Auto. Or better yet, omit the `MarshalAs` attribute altogether and just use the default marshalling. The CLR knows what it's doing for string types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can. You just need to use the `[return:]` attribute syntax, for example:

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]
```

But in your case, there is no marshalling to do. Marshalling is not needed to convert integral types like that, so just use the second form in your example.

If you really want, you could write a public method that called `GetFileAttributes()` which checked the return value for validity.

Comment: Does it just work for unmanaged types ? Or can I also marshal to managed types ?

Comment: @mini-me `MarshalAs` only works for the types for which the [`UnmanagedType enum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedtype.aspx) has values.

Comment: Ya, it's kind of obvious. But I meant marshaling the other direction. It seems marshaling works only `from managed to unmanaged` code.

Comment: @mini It works in both directions. Return values come from unmanaged to managed code. So do `out` parameters, and special ones like `StringBuilder`.